Which class is the language MAX-CLIQUE in?
We define $$ֿ\text{Max-Clique} = \{\langle G, k\rangle: \text{$G$ is an undirected graph, and the largest clique of $G$ has exactly $k$ vertices}\}$$
Is this language in $\text{NP}$ or in $\text{coNP}$?
What if we assume that $\text{P = NP}$, would this imply that the language is in $\text{P}$?
My attempts:
I tried to consider the complement language $\overline{\text{Max-Clique}}$, but I did not get very far.
Also, under the assumption that $\text{P = NP}$, I described the following Turing machine $M$:
Given input $\langle G, k\rangle$, $M$ opereates as follows:

initialize $i$ to 0.

While $i$ in not bigger than $|V|$:


2.1 Run Mclique on $\langle G, i\rangle$. If accepted, $i++$ and return to 1.
2.2 Else, proceed to 3.

if $i = k$, accept. Else, reject.

Where, Mclique is a machine that decides $\text{CLIQUE}$, and we know it's polynomial because of the assumption, hence $\text{Max-Clique}\in \text{P}$.

Consider the language $\text{Clique}= \{(G,k): \text{ $G$ has a clique of size at least $k$}\}$, and consider the language $L= \{(G,k): \text{ all the cliques in $G$ are of size  at most $k$}\}$.
It is not hard to see that $\text{Max-Clique} = \text{Clique} \cap L$. Also, $\text{Clique} \in \text{NP}$ and $L\in \text{coNP}$. Note that we have shown that Max-Clique actually belongs to the complexity class $\Sigma^p_2$ as $(G,k)$ is in Max-Clique iff there exists a Clique of size $k$, and all subsets of vertices of size at least $k+1$ are not a clique in $G$.
Anyway, the language Max-Clique does not appear to be in $\text{NP}$: given $(G,k)$, it is not clear if there is a short witness to whether the largest clique in $G$ is of size $k$.
The language  does not appear to be in $\text{coNP}$, either: there is no easy way to prove that $(G,k) \notin \text{Max-Clique}$ when the largest clique in $G$ has size smaller than $k$.
Now as $\text{P = NP} \to \text{P= NP = coNP}$, and as $\text{P}$ is closed under intersection, we get that if $\text{P= NP}$, then Max-Clique is in $\text{P}$.

For the part of proving Max-Clique is in P I must describe a TM, as I wrote, so this doesn't work for me. Regarding the first part - how do I prove that L∈coNP? (also, I only know the classes P, NP and coNP. What's the Σ one?)
I edited the question to explain what I was having difficulties with on that part of the question, maybe it'll help clarify things.

@Danielle the problem is unlikely to be in NP or coNP. $\Sigma^p_2$ is a complexity class in the polynomial hierarchy. see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy

@Danielle Regarding a description of a TM, that should be immediate from what I wrote. Given two polytime TMs for clique and L, it is easy to build a polytime machine for their intersection. Or simply use the fact that P is closed under intersection
